# Eclipse: Turn off project specific code formatters

Tags: eclipse

I have a project where every plugin project has specific format settings. It makes perfectly sense to use a single format setting for versioned source code but when working local I want to use my own formatter. I want to be able to say: It's okay that you have a project specific setting but I want to overwrite it with this global setting here. I want it always off when I'm working on it and only when I check in a new version of a file I want to use the project-specific format setting.

How can I temporarily deactivate the project specific formatting settings without doing it manually every time?

Comment: You want it *temporary deactivate* but you don't want do do it manually? In which Situations you want it off?

Comment: The project has about 50 pluging and each has a project specific setting. I want to be able to say: It's okay that you have a project specific setting but I want to overwrite it with this global setting here. I'm afraid it only works the other way around but asking can't hurt. I want it alway off when I'm working on it and only when I check in a new version of a file I want to use the project specific setting.

Comment: What SCM tool are you using? cvs, svn, git?

Comment: By the way, why not just avoid using the code formatter altogether? You don't *have* to invoke it on code you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

Besides clicking on every single Project and changing it, there is no Built-In way to do it.

You could do this:

The Configuration for the Project specific formatter is (at least in my Eclipse Mars 4.5.0) saved in the File `<your-project>.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`.

You could make a Backup of all those Files (e.g. save them as `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs.project-specific`) with the Project Specific Settings.

Then change all Projects manually to Workspace Settings and make another Backup (`org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs.workspace`).

Use then a Batch File to overwrite the default `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` with the Settings you want, after a Workspace Refresh Eclipse should register the new Settings.

If you use Git, you could use the `stash` function to change the Files back and forth, instead of backing up Files and a Batch File.